# MediaController/VideoView causes android.view.WindowLeaked

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have the following code which uses a VideoView and MediaController:

```
    FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this) {
        @Override
        public void hide() {
            // do not hide
        }

        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
            }

            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    };
    mediaController.setAnchorView(frameLayout);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.meditation);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mediaController.show(0);
        }
    }, 100);
```

The problem is when the activity finishes, I get the following error in my log:

> 10-28 05:57:16.075 6535-6535/com.kjdion.anxietynow E/WindowManager:
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.kjdion.anxietynow.MeditationActivity has leaked window
>   DecorView@13fd277[] that was originally added here
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:485)
>                                                                           at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
>                                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
>                                                                           at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:364)
>                                                                           at
>   com.kjdion.anxietynow.MeditationActivity$2.run(MeditationActivity.java:53)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Despite this error, everything works perfectly.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you override the hide method of the controller so that it doesn't hide. Remove that if you can and the code should work fine.